# Function describing pH vs. volume of base used in titration

Tags: acid-base, titration

> Sketch a graph of $\mathrm{pH}$ vs. volume when $\pu{50.0 cm^3}$ of $\pu{1 M}$ $\ce{HCl}$ is titrated with $\pu{1 M}$ $x\,\pu{cm^3}$ $(x \in (0,50))$ of $\ce{NH3}.$

As $\ce{HCl}$ fully dissociates, I know that

$$
\mathrm{pH} = \mathrm{p}[\ce{HCl}]. \tag{1}
$$

When $x\,\pu{cm^3}$ of $\ce{NH3}$ is added, $x\,\pu{cm^3}$ of $\ce{HCl}$ reacts. So, I can write the concentration of $\ce{HCl}$ as the function of $x$ this way:

$$
\mathrm{pH} = -\log\frac{c_0(\ce{HCl})\cdot V(\ce{HCl})}{ V_\mathrm{tot}} = -\log\frac{0.1(50-x)}{50+x}. \tag{2}
$$

Is this function correct? I am doing high school chemistry, hence my knowledge in chemistry is quite limited.

Comment: pH=-log ( [H+(aq)])  // Consider pH  buffering by pair NH3/NH4+, as NH3 is a weak base.

Comment: Good enough for high school IMO (and nice job with formatting, although I corrected it a bit), but @Poutnik's comment is worth considering. Probably you could tweak your question a bit since currently it appears to one of the [am-I-right type questions, which are usually getting closed](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3396/policy-on-amirite-questions).

Comment: related https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/117984/how-to-derive-the-conductivity-titration-curve-which-accounts-for-salt-formation